# Changing a variable that uses get set from a class that doesnt derive from monobehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

Coding Question

I am using a unity asset for the car controller and want to adjust the MaxTorque. it is a get set that comes from a class that doesnt derive from monobehaviour. Heres the code:

`public float MaxRPM { get { return CarConfig.MaxRPM; } }`

`public class CarConfig { public float MaxRPM = 7000; }`

Comment: just like components, you find the class instance, and get the public variable you just cant find it with findobject, or getcomponent.. but this code lives somewhere, where ever it is, you need to reference its instance

Answer (score 0):

bugfinder you answered it thank you!

I didnt have to assign it just call it thank you sir!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).